# Time series Classification - is LSTM better than XGBoost?

Tags: python, classification, time-series, lstm, xgboost

My question is whether LSTM RNN is a better predictor of a label (note not forecaster) than XGBoost.  Thus far I have had moderate success with XGB but I wonder if the tree nature, random start and non sequential elements with time window data is preventing further improvements.

I have motion data, accelerometer & gyro data on 3 axis at 60 hz.  I am trying to then classify movements from the data.  I have created time windows for these shots which are consistent and applied an XGBoost algorithm to this data.  All I feed to the algorithm is the time series window - 30Hz for the 6 axis so 180 data points.  I have 10,000 events that I have labelled.

I have 5 categories which I am trying to classify.  Categories 1 & 2 have accuracy of 90%, and these take up the majority of the data.  The prediction accuracy of the 3 remaining labels is nowhere near as good, between 30% & 60%.  I have tried cutting the data differently to build models which focus on differently elements, I have also raised the weight of the less well predicted events.  I have tried creating features and modelling on this instead of the raw data but the accuracy was far worse.

I have one last idea for how to cut the data so that there is a better classification, but this requires relabelling a lot of data.

I have used LSTM before but this would require relearning from my side and so am not sure about the benefits, nor can I find clear answers on if XGB is inappropriate / LSTM is better for time series classification.

Below is an example of how the data looks using one axis on accelerometer data.
[image]